# How can gpx track add to quadtree?

Tags: java, android, quadtree, gpx

Hi
I have a problem work whit very big gpx tracks for Android. I would like to add small parts of track to quadtree, and only this small parts draw to the display. My real problem is how implement a good quadtree structure for this problem.
Thanks, and sorry for the language mistakes, I´m not so good in english.

Comment: Using a quadtree is a good idea. If you have big variations in altitude, you might want to use an octree